# Embedding Layer word embeddings in NLP

Tags: nlp, neural-network, lstm, word-embedding

I am learning about word embeddings and using them in the LSTM model. I understand that the Embedding layer is used as the first layer to map word embeddings to the padded tokenised datasets.

Can we not directly feed the padded embedded dataset instead of the padded tokenised dataset to the LSTM directly, without an embedding layer?

If yes, then what is the significance of one over the other method?

I'm sorry if my question is unclear or very basic, I'm trying to understand each step in detail.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we not directly feed the padded embedded dataset (...) to the LSTM directly (...)?

If I understood correctly, you're basically describing static embeddings. Static, because by feeding pre-computed embeddings into an LSTM Model, the embeddings themselves won't change during training.

> If yes, then what is the significance of one over the other method?

Dynamic / Contextual Embeddings can be updated during training and thus better fit certain tasks. When you have high quality & domain specific embeddings that represent your data well enough, static embeddings like you described could be sufficient. Likewise, if you are limited to a small dataset or do not have a lot of computational power, static embeddings probably will perform better.

Note: A combination of both is possible as well (i.e. initialize an embedding layer with pre-trained embeddings and fine-tune during training).